# Can we get the portfolio size approximation from P&L

Tags: portfolio, international-finance

Im wondering if we can get the portfolio size approximation, if we have the volatility and -/+ pnl of the portfolio ? Is there a method or a formula ?
Thank you

Comment: It's very important

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be related to *personal* finance.

Answer (score 1):

Volatility is  measure of the price dispersion of a security.  It has nothing to do with the market price of the security or portfolio.

As for P&L, in terms of gross profit, if I told you that a portfolio's gain was $10k, how would you know whether it was a a $10k portfolio that doubled or a $100k portfolio that went up 10% (the same $10k)?

In terms of percentage gain, if I told you that a portfolio went up 10%, how would you know if it was a $10k or a $100k portfolio?

Without additional data points, there's no way to back figure the portfolio's size.

Comment: The only info I have is this :the annualised volatility of 9%. Thedaily P&L is in the range of +/ - $10,000. the goal is to find an approx of ptf size ?

Comment: @Gogo78 For what purpose?

Comment: Work related, just want to know if there’s a solution possible